# Deployment Issue with React project on now,sh

Tags: reactjs, vercel

***[UPDATE] The problem is caused by the conflict between yarn and npm. I run yarn install && now, then it runs as smooth as before.***

I deployed my create-react-app project successfully yesterday. After I updated the now-cli to 18.0.0 this morning, I cannot re-deploy the project for updating the content.

This is what I got when I try the `now` command:

```
now
Now CLI 18.0.0
⠏ Deploying xxx/yyyy Error! ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/yyyy/Desktop/react-page/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn-jsx/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you tried with by clearing cache

Comment: I do. I tried `npm cache clean --force`, still getting the same result.

Comment: Its seems some folder is missing can you run your command prompt in administrator mode and try .

Comment: I tried. Got the following result: `Error! Checking for updates failed
Now CLI 18.0.0 Now CLI 18.0.0
⠏ Deploying xxx/yyyy Error! ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/yyyy/Desktop/react-page/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn-jsx/node_modules/.bin/acorn'`

Comment: can you check acorn-jsx this module is exist or not under node_modules folder .

Comment: Problem solved. The problem is caused by the conflict between yarn and npm. I run `yarn install && now`, then it runs as smooth as before.